# Show that,the curve $c:(0,2\pi)\rightarrow C$, with $c(t)=f(e^{\lambda t},t)$ intersects the cone at a constant angle.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $C:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3|z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}\setminus\{0\}$
>
> $f(u,v)=(u*cos(v),u*sin(v),u)$, where U is
>
> $U:=\{(u,v)\in R^2\ | 0<u,0<v<2\pi \}$
>
> show that the trace of the curve $c:(0,2\pi)\rightarrow C$, with $c(t)=f(e^{\lambda t},t)$ intersects
> the rulings on the cone at a constant angle.

the general formula for the angle between two intersecting curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ on the surface is

$cos(\theta)=\frac{\gamma_1'\cdot\gamma_2'}{|\gamma_1'|\cdot|\gamma_2'|}$ and in this case this makes no sense, because $c$ is depending of only one parameter ($t$), but can we ignore $u$ and consider only $f_v$

Comment: Not sure I understand your question ("...can we ignore $u$ and consider only $f_v$?"), but you have a parametrization of $c$ (by setting $u=e^{\lambda t}$ and $v=t$), and can easily find vectors tangent to the generators (or can parametrize the generators if you prefer to use your formula for $\cos\theta$).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Here's a view from the bottom of the cone.